# Add files to system image in Yocto

Tags: docker, yocto, bitbake

I try to add two files to my system image using Yocto. I use the following code that does not give errors and is added to the conf/local.conf configuration file:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI += " \
    file://rootfs.tar.gz;unpack=0 \
    file://Dockerfile \
"

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${datadir}
    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/rootfs.tar.gz ${D}${datadir}
    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/Dockerfile ${D}${datadir}
}

FILES_${PN} += " \
        ${datadir}/rootfs.tar.gz \
        ${datadir}/Dockerfile \
"
```

However, my files are not present in the generated root filesystem, do you have any ideas why ? I already read a lot of posts on different forums but none of the solution worked.

EDIT : The code is in a file called "nested-containers.bb" inside a custom meta-layer. Here is the tree :

```
../sources/meta-custom
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
├── conf
│   ├── bblayers.conf.sample
│   ├── layer.conf
│   ├── local.conf.sample
│   └── machine
├── recipes-core
│   ├── nested-containers
│   │   ├── files
│   │   └── nested-containers.bb
```

The following line was added to conf/local.conf : IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nested-containers" inside the build directory.

Comment: small question to understand better what you have done.  This code should be in a bb file in a meta layer that is added to the project.  And not in the conf/local.conf file.  There, you could add that the recipe should be part of the image.

Comment: Yes excuse me that was not very clear. The code is in a recipe file called "nested-containers.bb" inside a custom meta-layer. I only use the conf/local.conf file to add "IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " package-name".

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the answer to this question was found. After research, it seems that the recipe needs a little more information:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Import nested containers to system image"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI += " \
    file://rootfs.tar.gz;unpack=0 \
    file://Dockerfile \
"

FILES_${PN} += " \
        ${datadir}/rootfs.tar.gz \
        ${datadir}/Dockerfile \
"

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/
    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/rootfs.tar.gz ${D}${datadir}
    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/Dockerfile ${D}${datadir}
}
```

Unfortunately, I still don't really understand why the previous recipe didn't work. It seems that the FILES_${PN} must be described before the do_install().

Answer (score 0):

Create a recipe with your code, and use `IMAGE_INSTALL` to install the package into an image(rootfs) as shown below. Refer  [Yocto ref-manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_INSTALL) for more usage

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " package-name"
```

Comment: @fnx_qt if i am not wrong, are you trying to add 'rootfs.tar.gz' inside roofts?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I already add this line in the conf/local.conf file. Here is my layer with the recipe:

my recipe is in a file called nested-containers.bb. The folder containing the recipe is also called "nested-containers" and has another folder called files that contains the two files that I try to copy.

However that doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you're correct I try to add rootfs.tar.gz inside /usr/share/ inside the generated rootfs

Comment: Can you make sure that your files(rootfs.tar.gz & Dockerfile) are present inside {WORKDIR}/image/usr/share of 'nested-containers'?

Comment: Got the following result:

./tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/nested-containers/1.0-r0/image/usr/share/rootfs.tar.gz

Comment: Are you trying to add it to core-image-minimal? or your own image?. If this is needed for all images then add IMAGE_INSTALL in local.conf, otherwise its good to add IMAGE_INSTALL in bbappend to your image recipe

Comment: I add it to core-image-minimal as I only use this image for my builds. This would be necessary for all images so I think that adding IMAGE_INSTALL in local.conf is a good choice ?

Comment: as it is core-image-minimal i would recommend to use this CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "package-name" to conf/local.conf

Comment: this is really strange, can you try 'btibake -e image-name' and check is something overriding your IMAGE_INSTALL

Comment: The IMAGE_INSTALL seems correct. It contains nested-containers : IMAGE_INSTALL="packagegroup-core-boot  openssh kernel-modules nested-containers docker python3-docker-compose state-scripts mender"

Comment: I have tried same scenario using IMAGE_INSTALL_append, i can see that files are available in rootfs. Try core-image-minimal once after cleaning

Comment: Do you have specific instructions on how to clean the project?

Comment: try this bitbake -c cleanall core-image-minimal

Comment: Did not work... I don't know what could be creating the problem

Comment: Finally, yes. Just posted the answer.

Comment: Its really strange, I have tried with your recipe in question, it works. Might be some other problem, because your recipe was already successful, but issue was with adding to image.